# Como Sobrepor uma Imagem com outra?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tendo problemas em posicionar uma imagem atrás da outra sem ser usando `position absolute/fixed`. Quando se usa divs no lugar de imgs, se você aplicar um `float:left`, ela fica no contexto acima das outrs divs, ficando sobreposta em relação as outras divs, mas com img isso não funciona.

Exemplo com DIVS:

```css
.wrap-elEx {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
.elEx {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}

.elEx_first {
  background-color: #8E44AD;
  float: left/* Esse elemento ficará a frente do outro */
}
.elEx_last {
  background-color: #23b14d
}
```

```html
Exemplo com DIV
<div class="wrap-elEx">
  <div class="elEx elEx_first"></div>
  <div class="elEx elEx_last"></div>
</div>

Exemplo com IMG
<div class="wrap-elEx">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KJHh65N.jpg" class="elEx elEx_first">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/G6WP6yB.jpg" class="elEx elEx_last">
</div>
```

Comment: Eu achei que era por conta do display block que as divs tem por padrão, mas não, elas se comportam de maneiras diferentes mesmo, não sei por qual motivo, e agora fiquei curioso rsrs. Show de bola a pergunta!

Comment: Já penseu em usar um `pseudo-elemento` para fazer isso?

Comment: tem que ser imagens diferentes, então um `pseudo-elemento` não funcionaria creio eu

Comment: Jef funciona com imgs diferentes sim, vou editar minha resposta e colocar uma opção desse tipo, mas o pseudo elemento não é direto na tag img mas sím na div em que a img está dentro!

Comment: Cara até consegui fazer com pseudo-elemento, mas ou vc usa o content:url() com a imagem já no tamanho certinho que vc precisa, ou vc vai ter que usar a img como background-image desse ::after. Alé disso vc vai precisar colocar position:relative na div que vai receber esse pseudo elemento, então acho que essa opção não vai te servir... Mas se quiser me fala que eu faço um edit na minha resposta com essa opção

Comment: opa pode mandar a resposta, qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda

Comment: Ok jovem editei a resposta com o que eu consegui fazer usando o pseudo-elemento...

Answer (score 1):

Cara vc pode usar `transform:translateX(-100%)` na segunda imagem para coloca-la por cima da primeira, não precisa usar `position` ou `float`

Segue o exemplo.

```css
.wrap-elEx {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}
.elEx {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}

.elEx_first {
  background-color: #8E44AD;
}
.elEx_last {
  background-color: #23b14d
}
img.elEx_last {
    transform: translateX(-95%);
}
```

```html
Exemplo com IMG e transform: translateX de -95% para vc ver que ficou por cima mesmo... não tem float ou position
<div class="wrap-elEx">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KJHh65N.jpg" class="elEx elEx_first">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/G6WP6yB.jpg" class="elEx elEx_last">
</div>
```

**OBS 1:** Importante... o transforme só joga uma imagem para cima da outra, porém ela continua ocupando o espaço onde deveria estar, então se vc colocar por exemplo um texto após a segunda imagem vc vai ver que vai ficar um espaço "vazio" entre as imagens sobrepostas e o texto...

**OBS 2:** Não sei se é o seu caso, mas vc pode usar um `pseudo-elemento` para colocar uma imagem por cima da outra tb, sem precisar de incluir outra img direto no html

Caso queira usar segue uma opção com pseudo-elemento. Mas como falei no comentário *"ou vc usa o `content:url()` com a imagem já no tamanho certinho que vc precisa, ou vc vai ter que usar a img como `background-image` desse `::after`. Além disso vc vai precisar colocar `position:relative` na div que vai receber esse pseudo elemento"* Expanda o código abaixo para ver o código direitinho.

```css
.wrap-elEx {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrap-elEx::after {
    content: "";
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/G6WP6yB.jpg);
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 5px; /* o left tem que ser 0, só deixei 5 pra vc ver a img por baixo */
}
.elEx {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-elEx">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KJHh65N.jpg" class="elEx ">
</div>
```

Comment: tem que ser imagens diferentes, então um `pseudo-elemento` não funcionaria creio eu, a sua solução deixa parte da imagem sobreposta visível isso ta certo ou é só aqui que se comporta assim rsrs